# Multivariable extrema on restricted domain

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

I want to find $max/min$ of the function $f(x,y) = e^{3xy}$ in the first quadrant limited by the lines $y=2x$, $x=2y$ and the curves $xy=2$ and $xy=6$

Since $f(x,y)$ only has a saddle point, I guess I have to check the boundaries, but how do I go about doing that in this situation?

thank you

Comment: You must plug in the equation for the boundaries, e.g. $$y=2x$$ then you will get $$e^{2x^2}$$ etc.

Comment: As $\exp$ is an increasing function you only have to find the $\min$/$\max$ of $(x,y) \mapsto xy$.

As in your domain $2 \leq xy \leq 6$ and that $6$ and $2$ are reached you can conclude.

Comment: Ofcourse! ... Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the intersection point between the line which define the boundaries and then consider

- $y=2x\implies f(x,2x) = e^{6x^2}$ for $x\in[1,\sqrt 3]$
- $x=2y\implies f(2y,y) = e^{6y^2}$ for $y\in[1,\sqrt 3]$
- $xy=2\implies f(x,2/x) = e^{6}$
- $xy=6\implies f(x,6/x) = e^{18}$